# Dream Jobbers for Med Bay or Cloth Fabricator?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Has anyone seen dream jobbers yet for Med Bay or Cloth Fabricator?  When I was in the process of achieving Imperial Marches and of building Bongo Sandwiches I was receiving dream jobbers so it was fully staffed the moment it was complete.  With the latest two levels complete I have yet to receive someone to staff them.

Answer (score 2):

I am on iOS (1.6), too, but I have seen bitizens with both Med Bay and Cloth Fabricator dream jobs.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on iOS and have 3 med bay dream job bitizens, and one cloth. They will turn up!

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  I have one person for Cloth fabricators, and my spouse has one for Med Bay.  We both have Android devices.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about the potential difference in devices.  I'm on iOS.

Comment: I also am on Android.  I have seen 2 for Cloth Fabricators, but 0 for Med Bay.